# Java SecretKeyFactory generated key is same as input password

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, secret-key

I'm trying to generate a secret key using PBE but the secret key generated by the SecretKeyFactory is exactly the same as the input password. I've tried different algorithms, iteration counts etc. and it is still the same so I feel I'm missing a step here.

```
public SecretKey generateKey(String password, String salt) {
    char[] passChars =   password.toCharArray();
    byte[] saltBytes =   salt.getBytes();
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory =   SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
    PBEKeySpec keySpec  =   new PBEKeySpec(passChars, saltBytes, 2048, 128);
    SecretKey secretKey =   keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    byte[] encodedKey =   secretKey.getEncoded();
    System.out.println("key: " + new String(encodedKey));

    return new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, "AES"); 
}
```

EDIT: if I use the algorithm "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" then the key generated is different from the password, but how come the algorithm I'm using is generating a key that is exactly the same as the input password?

Comment: You're just converting the input data into a `SecretKey` object. There is no secret key generation here.

Comment: @EJB Then what is the point in specifying the algorithm, iteration count, key size etc.? Will these parameters be used when I encrypt/decrypt?

Comment: @joe They have to be passed in a second time as the third parameter to `Cipher#init`. I also thought it was strange, but it's the way it is (duh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate a `SecretKey` using the SecretKeyFactory `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128` you will get an instance of `com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKey` and this class has the "special feature" that it returns the original "key" (aka password) when calling `getEncoded()` and not the cryptographic key material. If I understand it correctly the key derivation will not be made by the KeyFactory but by the Cipher itself.

Therefore you should not try to convert the `SecretKey` instance into a `SecretKeySpec` instance; instead just use the generated `SecretKey` instance in the correct cipher instance:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
```